# WordPress loop breaking page, loading blank page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm an apprentice WP developer and am trying to wrap up a project for work. I'm trying to loop in the first 6 or so posts on the homepage, but every time I add the loop the page breaks and loads empty (except for the header).

I'm using the HTML5 blank WordPress theme as the basis for the custom theme I'm developing and using ACF to create a custom page builder. The homepage is loading from page.php. Running WP 4.9.5.

```
<?php $args = array ( 'post_type' => 'post' );
$post_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>

<?php if($post_query->have_posts()): ?>

<?php while($post_query->have_posts() : $post_query->thepost(); ?>

<h2>THIS IS A TEST</h2>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); endwhile; ?>

<?php else :?>

<p>Whoops. No posts.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using so we can correct it

Comment: We're going to need a bit more from you to help out, as @ColinGell mentioned. Perhaps a test link, or the code on the actual page you're trying to load would be helpful.

Comment: First thing you do is set up WP_DEBUG https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress to find what is wrong. Then look at https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem: `$post_query->thepost();`. It should be: `$post_query->the_post();`. And you're missing a parenthesis after `while($post_query->have_posts()`.

Also, `wp_reset_postdata()` should be called **after** the while loop.

Here's the updated code (with a couple of tweaks):

```
<?php

$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $post_query->have_posts() ):

    while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

<?php
else : // No posts found.
?>
    <p>Whoops. No posts.</p>
<?php
endif;
```